# Intermitent high latency caused by Cablemodem

Tags: networking, wireless-router, ethernet, cable-modem, pcl

I have 2 computers conected to my Thompson model TCW770. I have been experimenting connection problems while playing online in different games. I have some seconds every 2-5 minutes that the game is freeze and latency go until 800 ms.

I have a computer with windows preview 10, connected using a PLA. No problems since 3 years, but if now I ping the cablemodem I get:

```
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2755ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
------------
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=884ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
-------------
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1627ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
```

And with another computer with linux mint, connected directly to cablemodem I have the same problem:

```
from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=265 ttl=64 time=0.530 ms 64 bytes 
from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=266 ttl=64 time=0.530 ms 64 bytes 
from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=267 ttl=64 time=917 ms 64 bytes 
from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=268 ttl=64 time=0.412 ms 64 bytes 
from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=269 ttl=64 time=0.500 ms
```

The cablemodem is new. I have changed it today, but the problem persist. How could I solve it?

Comment: The game freezing wouldn't be caused by latency though.  I would contact my service provider and request they verify the modem has their current firmware on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some test and ping to the internet provider too, I saw the latency was higher and same time, the problem was in my Cablemodem.

After disconnecting Wi-fi, using only ethernet and PLA, the extra long latencies dissapear, so this model has a problem with the Wifi.

After that, I connected again the Wi-fi, the problem didn't appear anymore. I don't know why but if you have the same problem you can do the same test and try this solution.

Otherwise, usually Cablemodems in Spain provider are not very good. It could be a good idea to buy an extra router to manage your private network and use the Cablemodem only to get t